# How to auto-mock custom business entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5, moq

I have a requirement to provide auto-mocking for 30 different types of custom business objects. In order to avoid the cost of writing manual mock-up codes for all public properties in each entity, I am looking for a lightweight framework that I can utilize in my project.
  Actually, this is not for unit testing but for "preview" functionality.

As for the behavior of mocking, I want to go by data type of the underlying entity.
  For instance,

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

All `int` properties = 1111, All `string` properties = XXXX, All `DateTime` properties will be `DateTime.Now` etc. I don't think I would need DI/IoC container because after preparing the mock-up entities, I have to explicitly pass all of those entities to a method (parameter `List<object> entities`).

Specifications:
ASP.NET C# (.NET 3.5) 
DotNetNuke (5.X.X)
MS SQL Server 2005

Thanks for your comments and suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a factory that create each object, you can call inside the factory a helper method that set your default values via reflection. Iterate object properties and set defaults for well known types.

```
var customer = CustomerFactory.Create();
```

else, you must call the helper method everytime you create a new instance:

```
var customer = DefaultValuesHelper.SetDefaults<Customer>(new Customer());
```

Comment: .. I think I failed to mention clearly that the same data type in different entities can have different mock-up values. For example: Customer.CustomerID (1111), Order.OrderID (2222).

Comment: you can do it putting with this logic into the helper